# Attempting to display a ActiveRecord fields from a joined table in a "show" view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have two tables that related to one-another called event_groups and events.
The models are as follows:

```
  class EventGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :event_group_name, presence: true, uniqueness: true has_many :events
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :events, allow_destroy: true
  end

  class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :event_group
    validates :event_group_id, presence: true
    validates :event_description, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  end
```

I generated the CRUD utilities using rails generate scaffold...
and am currently attempting to edit the events controller and the views to display data from the joined tables.

I have been able to successfully join the tables and display data for event_groups and events from the events index.html.erb view using the following:

```
  def index
     @events = Event.select ("events.id, event_groups.event_group_name, events.event_description, events.event_location, events.event_notes, events.days_from_event_start").joins(:event_group).order("event_groups.event_group_name, events.days_from_event_start") 
  end
```

This displays fine as a list with fields from both tables

```
 Event Group Name   Description            Location     Notes   DaysFrom1stEvent    
 Breeding           Stud to serve Mare     Stud Ranch   Costa   0                 Show    Edit    Destroy
 Breeding           Scan for pregnancy     Vet          None   14                 Show    Edit    Destroy
 Cycle Check        1st Cycle Check        Stud Ranch   None    0                 Show    Edit    Destroy
```

etc...

When "Show" is clicked, the intention is that the single line is displayed, but I am having problems when I try to join the table and display the fields from both tables.   I have no issue if displaying only the events fields, but I want to also display the event_group_name (example:breeding) in the show view.

I have tried many different things, the current attempt is the following:

```
 class EventsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :find_event_group, only: [ :show]
   before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

 def show

 end

 private
    def find_event_group
       @event_group = EventGroup.select("event_groups.id, event_groups.event_group_name").joins(:events).where('events.id = ?', params[:id])
    end

    def set_event
       @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    end

    def event_params
       params.require(:event).permit(:event_group_id, :event_description, :event_location, :event_notes, :days_from_event_start)
       params.require(:event_group).permit(:event_group_name, events_attributes: [:id, :event_group_id])
    end
 end
```

The show.html.erb code:

```
 <%= render 'layouts/maintainheader' %>
 <%= render 'layouts/referencefilesheader' %>
 <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>


 <p>
    <strong>event group:</strong>
    <%= @event_group.event_group_name %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <strong>Event description:</strong>
    <%= @event.event_description %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <strong>Event location:</strong>
    <%= @event.event_location %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <strong>Event notes:</strong>
    <%= @event.event_notes %>
 </p>

 <p>
    <strong>Days from event start:</strong>
    <%= @event.days_from_event_start %>
 </p>

 <%= link_to 'New Event', new_event_path %> |
 <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(@event) %> |
 <%= link_to 'Back', events_path %>
```

The error I get is: "undefined method `event_group_name' for #

I have also tried to get the data by using:

```
 class EventsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_event, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def show

  end

  private
     def set_event
         @events = Event.select("events.id, event_groups.event_group_name,events.event_description, events.event_location, events.event_notes, events.days_from_event_start").joins(:event_group).order("event_groups.event_group_name, events.days_from_event_start").where('events.id = ?', params[:id])
     end
```

With the change in the show.html.erb of:

```
    <p>
        <strong>event group:</strong>
        <%= @event.event_group_name %>
     </p>
```

The error I get from this attempt is:

```
  "undefined method `event_group_name' for #<Event:"
```

Any ideas?   I am really struggling with this - I have read and re-read RonR docs and many other problems logged here, to no avail...

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: `EventGroup.select("event_groups.id, event_groups.event_group_name").joins(:events).where('events.id = ?', params[:id])` should be `EventGroup.select("event_groups.id, event_groups.event_group_name").joins(:events).where('events.id = ?', params[:id]).first`, I guess

Comment: As per your code `@event_group` returns a collection of records not a single record. May be you should iterate through `@event_group` and display the `event_group_name`.

Comment: Where is the `@event_group.event_group_name` method defined?  Should it not be `@event.event_group.name`?

Comment: usmanali:   This worked, thanks.    I am confused about why it needed .first, though since there is only one events record with the events id of the params[:id] and only one event group record = "breeding".  I would think it would return only one record.??

Comment: Pavin:    You are right, but see my comment to usmanali.   I don't know why it returns more than one.   I am missing something....   Thanks for your response

Comment: Max:  In the controller, unless I am misunderstanding your question.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
def show
  @event = Event.find(params[:id])
  @event_group = @event.event_group
end
```

**Note** Those repetitive `event` prefixes everywhere make your code absolutely unreadable. Try to avoid such naming.

Comment: Too Easy!   Duh!   That's what a little (lot of?) ignorance, over-thinking and not using the "kiss" method gives you.   Thanks very much!